# Accessing variable inside a function from external file?

Tags: python, variables, module

I have a file
outSimulation.py this file has a function called
outlet1 and inside this function there is a variable called data

I want to access this data variable from another program called main.py

I have tried it with absolute imports

```
from outSimulation import outlet1 
values = outlet1.data()
```

but it doesnt work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you make the variable `data` global inside the external file and access it with `outSimulation.data`?

Comment: `data` is a local variable to your function `outlet1()`, you can not access it by `outlet1.data()`

Comment: as mentioned above you cannot access it, you will need to instantiate an outlet object first (assuming it's a class we are talking about)

Comment: What creates `data`? How do you know it will exist? What decides to make it stop existing? Names have scope in Python, and objects cease to exist when nothing refers to them any more.

Comment: `.data()` is a function call. Why would that work?

Comment: Thank you user7342539 that worked. Since data is a list I just accessed them like this
'outSimulation.data(1)'   etc.

Comment: Peter a stand alone file outSimulation.py creates data that I am feeding into a data base. however outSimulation.py has functions and inside those functions is "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot<sup>*</sup> access a variable which is local to a function from outside the function.

- If you want to access the value of `data` from a function which is *called* by `outlet1()`, you should pass `data` to that function.
- If you want to access the value of `data` *after* `outlet1()` finishes running, you should return `data` (possibly along with other things) from `outlet1()`.
- Alternatively, you can make `data` a module-level variable. Assuming you assign something to `data` within `outlet1()`, you would make it a module-level variable using the `global` keyword,

  ```
  def outlet1():
      global data
      # code
      data = ...
      # more code
  ```

  but this tends to be less clean than the other methods.

There are other solutions if `outlet1()` is defined within a class, but your question suggests that's not the case so I won't get into that.

---

<sup>*</sup>Well... uh, never mind. There are some wacky things you can do for debugging, but you're better off not considering those for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not classes, and are specifically designed so that you CAN'T do what you're trying to do. That's the whole basis of functional programming and the concepts behind encapsulation. Even if your function was a class, your code still wouldn't work because you're trying to call the variable as a function (by adding `()` to `data`).

Either create data as a global variable that can be referenced inside the function or have the function return a tuple with multiple items, including the original return value and the data variable (messy). You could also rewrite the function in an object-oriented way if that approach suits your problem domain, in which case your code above would make more sense.